# HttpServer Request get date range from query string

Tags: java, vert.x, http-get

I am new to Java and Vertx and I have a query string with the following format:

```
GET /examples/1/data?date_1[gt]=2021-09-28&date_1[lt]=2021-10-28
```

Here I have this `date_1` parameter which is within a certain range. I have been using `HttpServerRequest` class to extract simple parameters like integers but not sure how to proceed with these kind of range parameters.

With the simple parameters, I can do something like:

```
String param = request.getParam(paramName);
paramAsInteger = Integer.valueOf(paramAsString);
```

However, confused as to how to deal with the `gt` and `lt` options and the fact that we have same parameter twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you have difficulties parsing out these tokens. Here's how you can handle this.

1. The first thing to understand is that the parameter name is *NOT* "date1"
2. There are actually two parameters here
   2.1. "date_1[gt]" with a value of "2021-09-28"
   2.2. "date_1[lt]" with a value of "2021-10-28"
3. This is because in the URI parameter definition *everything* before the "=" sign is the parameter name and everything after is the parameter value.
4. You can just do

```
String dateAsString = request.getParam("date1[gt]");
paramAsInteger = toDate(dateAsString)
```

5. To implement the toDate() function read this simple article how to convert a string object into a data object using a standard library
   ([link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-date))

Comment: Ah thanks, I got confused with this article and thought gt and lt are somehow special: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/stu3/search.html#number

Comment: @Luca in the linked page the `lt` and `gt` are actually part of the parameter *value*, not the *name*. So if you get the value of the parameter you would get something like `gt100`.

Comment: ya, like I said, I got a bit confused...

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x will treat these parameters as two separate ones. So `RoutingContext#queryParam("date_1[gt]")` will only give you the value for `[gt]`. If you want the value for `[lt]` you need to get that separately.

That being said, you can move this tedious logic into an extra handler and store the values in the `RoutingContext`. Something like this might be easier:

```java
private void extractDates(RoutingContext ctx) {
    var startDate = ctx.queryParam("date_1[gt]");
    var endDate = ctx.queryParam("date_1[lt]");

    var parsedStartDate = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse(startDate.get(0));
    var parsedEndDate = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse(endDate.get(0));

    // things we put in the context here can be retrieved by later handlers
    ctx.put("startDate", parsedStartDate);
    ctx.put("endDate", parsedEndDate);

    ctx.next();
}
```

Then, in your actual handler you can access the two dates as follows:

```java
router.get("/date")
        .handler(this::extractDates)
        .handler(ctx -> {
            var responseBody = ctx.get("startDate") + " - " + ctx.get("endDate");
            ctx.end(responseBody);
        });
```

This allows you to keep your actual business logic concise.